# In Paraview (python), ExportView on an empty scene exports a .vtp with two objects

Tags: python, paraview

I am a bit confused by the ExportView command in python paraview. It creates two objects in the .vtp file that are not in the data I want to plot: a cone and a kind of symbol. I would like to remove these objects.

For example, I create an empty view:

```
from paraview.simple import *

renderView2 = FindViewOrCreate('RenderView2', viewtype='RenderView')
```

When I take a Screenshot (with `SaveScreenshot(SomePath, renderView2)`), I get as expected an empty image. But when I try to export in a .vtp (with `ExportView('test.vtp',view=renderView2)`), I get two objects: a cone and a symbol, as shown in the image.
[Two objects showing up in the .vtp file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZOPE.png)

What am I missing? How to remove these objects?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vtp this is particulary buggy but those objects are the Orientation Axis :)

You can fix it by hiding the axis before exporting:

`renderView2.OrientationAxesVisibility = 0`

related issue : https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview/-/issues/19301